# SQL Server TimeStamp not updating on data update

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

We have a SQL Server database upgraded from version 2005 to version 2008. This database has a table in which we are using a `TimeStamp` column. We use this column to update another table in the database.

Recently we noticed data not being updated on the client table. On a close look into the data we realised that some columns have different values, but the timestamp in both master and client tables is the same.

We understand that timestamp is calculated and maintained by SQL Server on addition/updation. My question: is there a scenerio where data on the row is changed, but timestamp does not get updated?

Comment: how do you copy the data between the tables?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive Timestamp is just a datatype.

If you do not want to supply the current time with each UPDATE, You could add a trigger to the table, and code in an update of the timestamp column (UPDATE inserted).

The value you are seeing now is either supplied in the INSERT statement or set by default, eg to get_date() by the table definition.

Comment: but I believe timestamp field is updated whenever a update on the row happens.

Comment: If you copy the data including the timestamp then you will have that same value.